# Grails share a GSP with multiple user

Tags: grails, render, gsp

I having a GSP when it is accessed by two or more user at same time, It will throw

`Row was updated or deleted by another transaction`

Is there any way to share the `render` safely

**Note**: There is no update or save operation while rendering

Answer (score 0):

## Dude ,Have you tired on the action who updates ,list and read or connected with the row can be

`@Transactional`  or do some `concurrencyStuff exception` handling

//Assume your domains are implemented just like or to be like this

```
class Author {
    String name
    Integer age
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

//option one in your controllers or service class

```
Author.withTransaction { status ->
    new Author(name: "Stephen King", age: 40).save()
    status.setRollbackOnly()
}
Author.withTransaction { status ->
    new Author(name: "Stephen King", age: 40).save()
}
```

//or

```
@Transactionl
def AuthorController () {

[list:list]
}
```

//or define a service like this

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
class BookService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    def listBooks() {
        Book.list()
    }

    @Transactional
    def updateBook() {
        // â€¦
    }

    def deleteBook() {
        // â€¦
    }
}
```

[for more visit :](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/services.html)  I hope this will be a bit useful ,Buddy!

Comment: Can you make it bit clear, if you don't mind share your email, I can share my code

Comment: Dude, thanks for your time, in my controller their is no problem, it is due to the delay in rendering process